# Updating layout from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My rails app has two pages based on two controllers/ views/ models..both controllers use a different layout

Controller A/ View A - Uses layout A - uses jquery js/jquery css 
Controller B/ View B - Uses layout B -  without jquery...standard default..

When  I navigate from a page A (based controller A/ View A) to page B ( based on controller B / View B) ...the layout change does not take effect immediately. I have to manually 'reload the page' from the browser...for the layout to kick in.

Why does the layout change not become effective automatically ? What can I do to make that happen ?

When I switch back from page B to Page A...the layout changes immediately....not sure why the same thing does not happen when I move from page A to B.

Added code for layouts:

```
-- Layout 1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </meta>
    <title>myapp1</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.mobile.min.css" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application","rails","jquery.min.js","jquery.mobile.min.js" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div data-role= "page" >
        <%= yield %>
        </div>
   </body>

</html>


-- Layout 2


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
        <title>myapp1</title>
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role= "page" >
    <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding excerpts of controller code where layouts are called:

```
controller # 1

class HeadersController < ApplicationController
  layout "xjquery"
  before_filter :authenticate

controller # 2

class RhattachmentsController < ApplicationController
  layout "xplain"

  def index
       rhid = session[:header_id]
```

Comment: Try redirect_to when you're navigating from page A to page B

Comment: I tried redirect_to. It does redirect BUT the new layout still does not kick in. When I manually refresh the page, the refreshed page uses the new layout. Is there a way to  call something like window.location.reload() ( or similar ) from within the controller or view to do a complete page refresh ?

Comment: Show your code where you're setting up the layouts

Comment: I just added the layout code to the original question.

Comment: I mean the controllers where you're choosing the layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me was adding  `:rel=>"external"` to the link_to which takes me from View A to ControllerB/View B. This forces a full page reload and also applies the new layout immediately.